Bizarre Ansible (and SSH) behavior
I'm experiencing two weird behaviours, out of nowhere, without any intentional change on my part:

Ansible (ansible all -i foo, -m ping) not only started to ask for the SSH key's password, but also the key's password is now (seemingly) incorrect. ❌

the very same key password is deemed correct by SSH (ssh -F /path/to/my_ssh_config foo) but the password only works in case 1.:

[✅ works] if typed relatively quickly;
[❌ doesn't work] if typed slowly, taking say a second between each key press;
[❌ doesn't work] if pasted.



Both Ansible and SSH prompt for the password with
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/foo/.ssh/bar':

(Ansible also adds 'a white key' Unicode grapheme after the :.)


ansible [core 2.17.1]
Python 3.11.5
OpenSSH_9.4p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
macOS 14.3 (23D56)


Relevant files:

/path/to/my_ssh_config, for both 1. (Ansible) and 2. (SSH) above:

Host *
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  User ec2-user
  IdentityFile /Users/foo/.ssh/bar
Host jump
  Hostname 34.1.1.1
Host foo
  ProxyJump jump
  Hostname 10.1.1.1


for 1. (Ansible) is below ansible.cfg, which is in the same directory from where the above Ansible command is run (ansible all):

[defaults]
host_key_checking = False
interpreter_python = auto
stdout_callback=community.general.yaml

[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -F /path/to/my_ssh_config


Does the behavior continue after a reboot? Can you try with a different keyboard?
